# add AsyncTask onPreExecute to fragment

Tags: android, android-asynctask, actionbarsherlock, fragment

I want to add a onPreExecute AsyncTask to a SherlockFragment but it cause error. My code is below. What is my problem on this code to add a dialog on preExecute AsyncTask?

```
public class customlist extends SherlockFragment  {
static final String URL = "esample";
static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
private static final String KEY_TAB_NUM = "key.tab.num";
 private ProgressDialog pDialog;


ListView list;
LazyAdapterbeth adapter;
XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

}


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    new getFeed().execute();

}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 

{
    View thisfragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dovomi, container, false);

    return thisfragment;
}




private class getFeed extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Document> {
  @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(customlist.this);
        pDialog.setTitle("Connect to Server");
        pDialog.setMessage("This process can take a few seconds to a few minutes, depending on your Internet Connection Speed.");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected Document doInBackground(Void... params) {

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        return doc;
    }
```

It causes an error in the line

```
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(customlist.this);
```

How  can I add a dialoge or progressbar in this fragment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ProgressDialog takes a Context as a parameter. Since you are using it in a Fragment you can use `getActivity()` instead.

Comment: How to use it please write the code as an example , Thanks

Comment: @Ghazanfari `new ProgressDialog(getActivity())`.

Comment: Thanks, but I have error like this : pDialog cannot be resolved